# CartoDB: Can I use some "if..then" structure or "loop" structure in popup custom HTML?

Tags: carto, infowindow

In CartoDB (https://carto.com/)'s popup CustomHTML, can I use some logic like "If..then", "loop" or so?

I want to use it for usecase something like below:

- Avoiding representation if attributes are null.
- Showing all images if image url list is given.

Would you give me the information for such function in CustomHTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CARTO infowindows use [Mustache templates](http://mustache.github.io/) to display the values of each point in the infowindows. You would need to go to the HTML version of the infowindow and write:

`<h4>c_distri</h4>
      {{#c_distri}}
        <p>{{c_distri}}</p>
      {{/c_distri}}
      {{^c_distri}}
        <p>No value</p>
      {{/c_distri}}`

- For the example I'm using a random column named `c_distri`.

This is "telling" to CARTO:

1- If there is a value (not nulls or empty cells) in the column named c_distri, display the values of the column within HTML paragraph tags.

`{{#c_distri}}
        <p>{{c_distri}}</p>
      {{/c_distri}}`

2- If there is no value (nulls or empty cells) in the column named c_distri, display the message "No value"  within HTML paragraph tags.

`{{^c_distri}}
        <p>No value</p>
      {{/c_distri}}`

The complete HTML code for the infowindow could be this one:

```
<div class="cartodb-popup v2">
  <a href="#close" class="cartodb-popup-close-button close">x</a>
  <div class="cartodb-popup-content-wrapper">
    <div class="cartodb-popup-content">

      <h4>c_distri</h4>
      {{#c_distri}}
                <p>{{c_distri}}</p>
        {{/c_distri}}
        {{^c_distri}}
            <p>No value</p>
        {{/c_distri}}

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cartodb-popup-tip-container"></div>
</div>
```

You can find detailed information about Mustache.js templates [here](http://www.elated.com/articles/easy-html-templates-with-mustache/).

Comment: Thank you!! That is exactly I want to have. But how can I access latitude/longitude of POI in template?

Comment: I tried {{lat}} {{latitude}} {{the_geom.0}} {{the_geom.lat}} {{the_geom.latitude}} or so, but not works..

Comment: it is not possible to display the coordinates from the_geom column in the infowindow. You could create a new column called" longitude" or "latitude" and populate it with the values from the longitude and latitude values from the_geom column. You could use SQL with the [ST_X()](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_X.html) and [ST_Y()](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_Y.html) functions to extract the longitude and latitude values from the_geom column

Comment: Thank you, I can extract them by SQL :

SELECT *, ST_X(the_geom) as lng, ST_Y(the_geom) as lat FROM table_name

Comment: yes or you could also create the new columns and then use a SQL UPDATE operation to populate those columns. For example: UPDATE tableName SET newColumn = ST_X(the_geom)