# Carto: Can I use some “if/then/else” structure in popup custom HTML?

Tags: carto, popup, html, if-else

I believe I am asking a question similar to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213222/cartodb-can-i-use-some-if-then-structure-or-loop-structure-in-popup-custom) that was asked a few years ago about popup functionality in the old CartoDB. I just tried my best to replicate the solution to that question in the newer Carto Builder, but I'm failing. (I tried using the `#` and `^` symbols in what I thought were similar places to where they were used in the solution to the question above; doing so didn't break the HTML, but it didn't work either).

**My algorithm is:**

If `<field_A>` is not null, show fields A, B, and C in the popup 
If `<field_D>` is not null, show fields D, E, and F in the popup

**Or, an alternate algorithm could be:**

If `<field_A>` is not null, show fields A, B, and C in the popup 
If `<field_A>` is null, show fields D, E, and F in the popup instead

**This is the default HTML** that Carto created for me to simply show fields A, B, and C in the popup. I'd like to edit this HTML to match my algorithm above. My arrows show where I think I need to edit the HTML, but I'm at a loss for how to actually edit it:

```
<div class="CDB-infowindow CDB-infowindow--dark js-infowindow" style="background:#2E3C43">
  <div class="CDB-infowindow-close js-close"></div>
  <div class="CDB-infowindow-container">
    <div class="CDB-infowindow-bg">
      <div class="CDB-infowindow-inner js-inner">
        <ul class="CDB-infowindow-list js-content">

          <li class="CDB-infowindow-listItem">
              <h5 class="CDB-infowindow-subtitle">field_A</h5>    <-- I think this is where I need to specify "if field_A is not null..."
            <h4 class="CDB-infowindow-title">{{field_A}}</h4>     <-- And this is where I need to specify "...then show field_A"
                                                                  <-- And then here is where I'd need to specify "...else show field_D" 
          </li>

          <li class="CDB-infowindow-listItem">
              <h5 class="CDB-infowindow-subtitle">field_B</h5>    <-- Repeat the above for the next set of fields
            <h4 class="CDB-infowindow-title">{{field_B}}</h4>

          </li>

          <li class="CDB-infowindow-listItem">
              <h5 class="CDB-infowindow-subtitle">field_C</h5>    <-- Repeat the above for the last set of fields
            <h4 class="CDB-infowindow-title">{{field_C}}</h4>

          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="CDB-hook">
      <div class="CDB-hook-inner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carto uses the [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) templating system for popups. They are "logic-less" however you can implement a bit of logic by bracketing the content you want given some condition using tags with `#` for "is true", `^` for "is false", and `/` as the closing tag.

Given the following data

```js
{ 
  "field_a": null, 
  "field_b": "some",
  "field_c": "thing",
  "field_d": "and",
  "field_e": "another",
  "field_f": "thing"
}
```

A workable template for your logic would look something like this

```html
<div class="CDB-infowindow CDB-infowindow--light js-infowindow">
  <div class="CDB-infowindow-close js-close"></div>
  <div class="CDB-infowindow-container">
    <div class="CDB-infowindow-bg">
      <div class="CDB-infowindow-inner js-inner">
        <ul class="CDB-infowindow-list js-content">
{{#field_a}}
          <li class="CDB-infowindow-listItem">
              <h5 class="CDB-infowindow-subtitle">field_a</h5>
            <h4 class="CDB-infowindow-title">{{field_a}}</h4>
          </li>
          <li class="CDB-infowindow-listItem">
              <h5 class="CDB-infowindow-subtitle">field_b</h5>
            <h4 class="CDB-infowindow-title">{{field_b}}</h4>
          </li>
          <li class="CDB-infowindow-listItem">
              <h5 class="CDB-infowindow-subtitle">field_c</h5>
            <h4 class="CDB-infowindow-title">{{field_c}}</h4>
          </li>
{{/field_a}}          
{{^field_a}}
   {{#field_d}}
          <li class="CDB-infowindow-listItem">
              <h5 class="CDB-infowindow-subtitle">field_d</h5>
            <h4 class="CDB-infowindow-title">{{field_d}}</h4>
          </li>
          <li class="CDB-infowindow-listItem">
              <h5 class="CDB-infowindow-subtitle">field_e</h5>
            <h4 class="CDB-infowindow-title">{{field_e}}</h4>
          </li>
          <li class="CDB-infowindow-listItem">
              <h5 class="CDB-infowindow-subtitle">field_f</h5>
            <h4 class="CDB-infowindow-title">{{field_f}}</h4>
          </li>
   {{/field_d}}
{{/field_a}}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="CDB-hook">
      <div class="CDB-hook-inner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Jeremy, thank you so much for this answer. Unfortunately, it's not working for me just yet. All I see are empty black pop-ups. I'm not sure how to share my HTML though to troubleshoot. But it looks exactly like yours just with my actual field names replacing "field_a," "field_d," etc.

Comment: Ah ha! Carto helped me to understand why it wasn't working. I didn't have the fields selected in Builder first before I applied the HTML. I guess doing that initializes them.

Comment: Ah, yes - that will decide what goes into the UTF grids that feed these.